# How do I pass my data from mongoDB using mongoose to my App.jsx?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, web-development-server

At the moment, I have App.js connected to the mongoDB using mongoose and i can read/write on the database on App.js. But I can't seem to find a way to pass that data im getting using a function to my App.jsx for it to render on react. Im currently rendering objects from a js file, restaurants.js, which i created to have some data to work with when i was building out the structure. Im just learning about react and mongo and i have exhausted all my current knowledge of javascript functions but i just cant get it to work. Please help

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/restaurantsDB")

const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    image: String,
    categories: [],
    restaurantID: Number,
    avgDeliveryTime: Number
});

const Restaurant = mongoose.model("Restaurant", restaurantSchema);

const restaurant = new Restaurant({

    name: "Death Star Burgers",
    rating: 4,
    image: "/assets/restaurant photos/rectangle 150.png",
    categories: ["burgers","fries"],
    avgDeliveryTime: 30
});

Restaurant.find(function(err,all){
    all.forEach(function(x){
        console.log(x.name)
    })
})
```

```
`import React from 'react';
import RestaurantCard from './RestaurantCard'
import Restaurant from '../restaurants'


function createRestaurantCard(restaurant){
    
    return <RestaurantCard


    key = {restaurant.id}
    id = {restaurant.id}
     name={restaurant.name} 
     image = {restaurant.image}
     ratings = {restaurant.ratings}
     categories = {restaurant.categories}
     averageDeliveryTime = {restaurant.averageDeliveryTime}


    />
    
}
function App() {
    return <div className='restaurant-grid'>
    {Restaurant.map(createRestaurantCard)}
    
    </div> 
    
}


export default App;
`
```

`const restaurantData=[
{
id: 0,
name: "Hyper Burgers",
image: "/assets/restaurant photos/rectangle 150.png",
categories: "burgers, chicken",
ratings: 5,
averageDeliveryTime: "30min"
},
{
id: 1,
name: "Death Steak",
image: "/assets/restaurant photos/steak.png",
categories: "steaks, chicken",
ratings: 4,
averageDeliveryTime: "40min"
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Dynasty Chinese Restaurant",
image: "/assets/restaurant photos/chinese.png",
categories: "rice, noodles",
ratings: 5,
averageDeliveryTime: "15min"
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Lefmagir Doner",
image: "/assets/restaurant photos/wrap.png",
categories: "wrap, sis kebab",
ratings: 2,
averageDeliveryTime: "50min"
}

]
export default restaurantData;

i tried using module.export but i couldnt return anything.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to do the fetching data part inside a useEffect hook and then you should have state and then you would setState the fetched data to cause a rerender inside your app.